# How to Disable TinyMCE editor on a per-page basis in Wordpress 3.X

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Is it possible to disable Wordpress's WYSIWIG editor on a per-post or per-page basis? I do not want to eliminate it entirely, as it does what i need for 90% of the pages. However, on the 10% of pages that need custom code fighting with it while it strips out tags, reformats paragraphs, etc is a bear.

I would like to have a few pages where the TinyMCE editor is totally disabled and it only shows code view, and the rest normal.

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to the question:  it might be possible to do it if you are willing to risk breaking the backend of the site but you would have to hard code which pages or posts don't see the editor and I don't think this is what you had in mind.

What I would do instead in this situation is train yourself to work in HTML view exclusively or investigate a different rich text editor with less obnoxious tendencies: http://wordpress.ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that does just this (I know this is an old Q, but for the sake of anyone who finds this on a search)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deactive-visual-editor/